# How to change hadoop conf directory location?

Tags: hadoop, configuration, location

In the exception stack trace I can see that my hadoop configuration is loaded from /etc/hadoop/conf.empty/hdfs-site.xml

How do I change it to /etc/hadoop/conf/hdfs-site.xml ?

Answer (score 3):

In principle you can load any `bash` script before loading the `hadoop` daemon, e.g. in `/etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-datanode` for datanodes.

You can add towards the top to this `init` script,

```
 export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf
```

Also, you can check whether this is overridden by hadoop in `/usr/lib/hadoop/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh`. A similar file should also be: `/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh`

Best way is to check, which are the files are getting called when hadoop calls the init script in `/etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-*`

Answer (score 1):

You can always set your configuration files from the command line via: (example ls)

> hadoop fs -conf configFile.xml -ls ./